# Axios cancel token outside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I`m using React with Redux and I have axios requests in the Redux actions. How I use CancelToken in this exemple? Over internet I found only the method where axios is inside the useEffect. I have the axios in the redux actions. Thanks!

> exemple component.js

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {getAction} from '../action';

export default function Test() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

React.useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(getAction());
}, []);
```

> exemple action.js

```
export const getAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
 await axios
  .get(`${URL}`)
  .then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ACTION,
      payload: res.data
    )}
  )
```

Comment: In which case do you want to cancel the Token? like if the API failed or something else?

Comment: I want to stop sending multiple requests on search when typing

Comment: you can use debounce input for that. see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input)